# how to check if a field exists in a specific document Mongodb using C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a WebAPI with asp.Net/C# and I'm using Mongodb . Before updating a specific document, I need to check if a field exists in the document or not and if not add the filed to the document. But **I don't know how I can check the existence of a field in a document**. To add the field I'm using this code:

```
var update = Bundle.Update.Set(b => b.followers, new List<User>());
int res = Bundle.UpdateOne(Bundle.Filter.Eq(b => b._id, id), update);
```

Thanks in advance.

I tried to use something like this but it returns null!!

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;               
var filter = builder.Exists("followers", false).ToBsonDocument();
var RetrievedData = Bundle.Collection().Find(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you show us what you already tried?

Comment: @Dave I added above the last thing I tried but no success!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Use Try/Catch as follows:

   ```
   var document = Bundle.Collection().Find(filter); // here is your BsonDocument
   try
      {
         document["fieldNameToCheck"] // if field doesn`t exist it throws KeyNotFoundException. If there are nested objects just follow the pattern: document["fieldName"]["fieldNestedToCheck"]
      }
   catch (Exception ex) when (ex is KeyNotFoundException)
      {
         // your logic for "the field wasn`t found in the document" case
      }
   ```
2. Use .Contains(), as follows:

   ```
   var exists = document.Contains("fieldNameToCheck");// if field exists it returns true
   // If you need to check the nested fields, you can do as follows:
   var nestedExists = document["fieldName"].ToBsonDocument().Contains("fieldNameToCheck"); // or:
   var nestedExists = document["fieldName"]["nestedFieldNameNextLevel"].ToBsonDocument().Contains("fieldNameToCheck");  // and so on...
   ```
3. And by using TryGetElement you can additionally get this element:

   ```
   BsonElement element; // it will contain found element if true for next line
   var exists =  document.TryGetElement("fieldNameToCheck", out element); // returns true if element is found
   ```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

You can check the existence of a field in a document by checking the Bson Value:

```
if (!document["fieldNameToCheck"].AsBsonValue is BsonNull)
{
   // the field exist...
}
```