# Get field from a sub object in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following document in MongoDB and I want to check if the field FileName has a specific value.

[image]

Following are my classes:

```
public class Invoice
{

    private InvoiceMetaData _metadata = null;
    private List<InvoiceColumns> _invoiceFields = null;
    public InvoiceMetaData Metadata
    {
        get
        {
            if (_metadata == null) _metadata = new InvoiceMetaData();
            return _metadata;
        }
        set { _metadata = value; }
    }
    public List<InvoiceColumns> InvoiceFields
    {
        get
        {
            if (_invoiceFields == null)
                _invoiceFields = new List<InvoiceColumns>();
            return _invoiceFields;
        }
        set { _invoiceFields = value; }
    }
}

 public class InvoiceMetaData
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FileProcessedOn { get; set; }
        public string DirectoryPath { get; set; }
    }
```

I've tried using the following but it's returning false even though documents with this filename exist.

```
string filename = "01.png";
 var collection = myDB.GetCollection<Invoice>(collection_name);
 var exists = collection.AsQueryable().Any(avm => avm.Metadata.FileName == filename);
```

I've also tried this but it's returning nothing i.e. List count is 0.

```
var query = Query<Invoice>.EQ(u => u.Metadata.FileName, filename).ToBsonDocument();
var exist = collection.Find(query).ToList();
```

Also tried this and list Count is 0,

```
 var filter1 = Builders<Invoice>.Filter.Eq(u => u.Metadata.FileName, filename, filename);
 var result = collection.Find(filter1).ToList();
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The filename is in the class InvoiceMetaData and only one item exists : myDB.InvoiceMetaData.Filename

Comment: Yes but i'm creating a property of invoice Metadata in Invoice Class. Cant't I get it through Builders<Invoice>.Filter.Eq(u => u.Metadata.FileName, filename, filename);

Comment: it is not an enumerable item(nor a collection).  There is only one copy of the properties.  You should be able to get it through : myDB._metadata.FileName;  This object is your collection :private List<InvoiceColumns> _invoiceFields = null;

Comment: myDB._metadata.FileName gives an error "MongoDatabaseBase' does not contain a definition for '_metadata' and no accessible extension method '_metadata" 
Really Sorry to bother again this is my first time working on this.

Comment: There is an inconsistency between the model of the database and the classes in c#.  See : https://medium.com/@hanjchen/mongo-weekly-mongdb-insertion-and-data-modeling-in-c-2e5d70388a0a

Answer (score 0):

I haven`t worked with this for a while. But this can be helpful for you:

- [how to check if a field exists in a specific document Mongodb using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824533/how-to-check-if-a-field-exists-in-a-specific-document-mongodb-using-c/55105384#55105384)
- As i remeber, you can do something like that:

  ```
  var collection = myDB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection_name); // you use Invoice, try BsonDocument
  var documents = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList(); // this one should get you all documents
  var fieldName = "Metadata" // name of field you need data from

  foreach (var document in documents)
  {  
    // this one should contain your metadata object from document, note it is BsonDocument   
    var metaDataObject= document.Contains(fieldName) ? document[fieldName].ToBsonDocument() : null;        

    var fileName= metaDataObject!= null ? metaDataObject["FileName"] : "No file name."; // should be your file name          

    // you also should be able to convert to dictionary, under this namespace MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument
    // var metadataDic= metaDataObject.ToDictionary();
    // var fileName= metadataDic["FileName"]; // should be your file name        
  }
  ```
- Filter examples:

  ```
  var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter; // in your example invoice, try BsonDocument
  var filter = builder.Eq("FileName", fileName);  
  var count = collection.Count(filter);
  ```